# Why would Guid.NewGuid() be generating an empty guid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, guid

I have a Guid.NewGuid() call that is creating an Empty Guid.

What would cause such a problem and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** The code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function CreateRow(rowValue As String) as String
    Dim rowPointer As Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid()
    Dim rowPointerValue As String = rowPointer.ToString()

    Try
        Dim result as Integer = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionString, "Sproc_Name", rowValue, rowPointer)

        Return result
    Catch ex as Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

**Edit:** Turns out that rowPointer was originally being passed to the SqlHelper and not rowPointerValue - This of course is passed as empty, as pointed out in the answers.  Changing it to rowPointerValue/rowPointer.ToString() fixed the problem.

Comment: How 'bout a little more- some context, and where you check the output

Comment: What is the string result of rowPointer.ToString()?
Or are you getting a null reference error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old problem in VB.NET. It is only the debug visualizer that is broken.

http://www.thesoftwaredevotional.com/2008/12/guid-visualizer-broken-in-vbnet.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing. Debugging of Guid.NeGuid() was showing that it's empty. Calling .ToString() fixed the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this code in VS2008 and the results are not what I expected.  It seems that the new guid is not created until the toString method is called.  After stepping through the code rowPointerValue does hold a string representation of the guid.

It seems to be using defferred execution?

Answer (score 1):

I've only experiened this problem in VB.NET and only while debugging.  Thanks 48494, for that info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim g As New Guid();

Dim whereDoYouWantToSeeIt As String = g.ToString();
```